# Ordenar componente DataTables por Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-datatables

Estou utilizando o componete [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) onde retorna os aniversariantes do mês. Estou ordenando em meu controller por dia, e o mesmo funciona corretamente em uma tabela normal. Existe uma forma de alterar o dataTable para ordenar conforme ele recebe os dados do controller?

Segue meu controller:

```
 public ActionResult Aniversariantes()
    {

        var usuarios = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(u => u.DtNascimento.Month == DateTime.Now.Month);
        var usuariosOrdenados = usuarios.OrderBy(u => u.DtNascimento.Day).ToList();
        return View(usuariosOrdenados);

    }
```

Minha View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario>


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Aniversariantes do Mes";
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">

</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h5><strong>Aniversariantes do Mes</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <table id="myTable" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome do Funcionário</th>
                    <th>Secretaria</th>
                    <th>Data do Aniversário</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.NmFuncionario
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.Descricao
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.DtNascimento.Day.ToString("00")/ @item.DtNascimento.Month.ToString("00")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#myTable").dataTable();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui, bastou adicionar o campo e a ordem de ordenação em meu script.

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#myTable").dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[2, "asc"]]
    });
});
```

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta para que fique mais claro que você encontrou a solução para seu problema!